How to use laravel nova trix field in own custom field?
Can someone please tell me how to use the included laravel nova fields in an own custom field. In my case I want to use the TrixField.vue in my custom field. I can't find how to implement this ...
<template v-for="(item, index) in texts">
            <input type="checkbox" :name="index"> {{ index }}
            <-- trix field instead of a textarea ?? -->
            <textarea class="w-full form-control form-input form-control-bordered">
                {{ item }}
            </textarea>
        </template>


I have figured out, just use the trix-editor like this:
<trix-editor />

